# Scroll event not firing until stopped scrolling on window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, dom-events

I have a scroll event that is attached to the window in a component. I want to console log the scroll position of the page. However if I move the scroll bar quickly I will only get the console log when I stop scrolling in Chrome. Here is my component:

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import _ from 'lodash';

export class HeroImage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
      this.handleScroll = this.handleScrollAnimation.bind(this);
   }


  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, false);
  }

  handleScrollAnimation() {
    // const heroImage = this.HeroImage;
    console.log('here');
    const doc = document.documentElement;
    const scrollPosition = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    console.log(scrollPosition);
    // heroImage.style.backgroundPosition = '50% 0';
    // const animationCopy = this.AnimationCopy;
    // if (this.isElementInViewport(animationTitle)) {
    //   animationTitle.classList.add('animated');
    // }
    // if (this.isElementInViewport(animationCopy)) {
    //   animationCopy.classList.add('animated');
    // }
  }

  render() {
    const styles = {
      heroImage: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.image})`
      }
    };
    return (
      <section className="hero-image">
        <div
          ref={c => {
            this.HeroImage = c;
          }}
          style={styles.heroImage}
          className="hero-image-bg"
          />
        <div className="hero-image-content-container">
          <div className="hero-image-content">
            <div className="corners corners-top-left"/>
            <div className="corners corners-bottom-left"/>
            <div className="corners corners-top-right"/>
            <div className="corners corners-bottom-right"/>
            <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

HeroImage.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  image: PropTypes.string
};
```

This is how I call the component on a page:

```
<HeroImage image={this.state.heroImage} title={this.state.title}/>
```

I've done so much googling I can't find the answer. I'm sure it's just a small change but do I need to move a scroll event to the page? That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Can you post more information?
I attempted to replicate this issue but had no problem.
Here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/vqrcs3px/

Comment: I see your example works how i expect. Let me put up a bit more code for you

Comment: I've added the whole component code and how i add it to the page for context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put this sample together based on something that I have done on a project at work. In this code snippet the scroll event fires as you scroll and not only once you are done.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {findDOMNode} from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      stuff: []
    }
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let stuff = this.state.stuff;
    for(let i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
      stuff.push(i);
    }
    this.setState({stuff});
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll() {
    let node = findDOMNode(this);
    let dimensions = node.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(dimensions);
  }

  createRow(s, i) {
    return (
      <h1 key={i}>Foo</h1>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       {this.state.stuff.map((s, i) => this.createRow(s, i))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am not entirely sure if I understand the difference between your code and mine, but this should work for you.

Comment: did you include App on a page? and the event was firing correctly? I can't see the difference from my code to yours but mine doesnt work :(

Comment: app is the component that is being injected to the main div on the index.html by reacdom.redner.

Comment: Just to make mine a bit more confusing is HeroImage is a component added to another component which is then rendered on the index.html

Comment: I can add that concept to my sample and see what happens.

Comment: that would be really helpful. i just think im just going wrong somewhere

Comment: OK I just added a component called Foo which handles the scrolling and is rendered by App which is rendered by react dom. Still works.

Comment: hmm okay. im not sure what to do with my code above and how to solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: does your console.log('here') fire only when the scrolling is done as well?

Comment: yer the console.log('here') fires every time but the scroll position doesn't

Comment: It some how has started working for me. not sure what has changed. Sorry for wasting your time. Also I appreciate your code example as it clarifys what i'm doing is correct.

Comment: hey great! no time wasted. If you figure where you went wrong, you may want to post it for others who stumble with this.